# Stack Exchange French Login page does not display well in Mozilla Firefox on my Pc

Tags: bug, design, ssl

I have noticed that the French StackExchange login pages does not display well in Mozilla Firefox 35.0.1 (the latest at the moment). When for example i visit https://french.stackexchange.com/ and i click on [Login](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=http%3A%2F%2Ffrench.stackexchange.com%2F) the page does not display well so i can not login with facebook or even a normal registration and log in.

This is what I see when I visit the French Stack Exchange and try to log in with  Mozilla Firefox

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCf4h.png]

**Please how to solve this ?**

Comment: Does it work when you go to that page and press Ctrl+F5?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Virus?? really?

Comment: What do you see if you go to: https://cdn.sstatic.net/french/all.css ?

Comment: I see This Connection is Untrusted

Comment: On my side that URL opens just fine with Firefox on Windows... either it's fixed or it's something wrong on your side.

Comment: Works for me in Firefox 35.0.1 on Linux. Firefox signals that the home page includes non-HTTPS elements (some favicons) but displays the page correctly anyway. The login page is fully HTTPS and displayed correctly.

Comment: Those who are downvoting, have you checked out the screenshot above ? I bet they are also other people having the same issue and can not even access the website to ask question about this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of Firefox does not accept Untrusted https. And StackExchange seems to be using a  sstatic.net CDN that Firefox identifies as Untrusted.

When you open the source [of the French Login Page of StackExchange](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=http%3A%2F%2Ffrench.stackexchange.com%2F), and click on [//cdn.sstatic.net/french/img/favicon.ico?v=7c7d63e627d7](http:////cdn.sstatic.net/french/img/favicon.ico?v=7c7d63e627d7) Firefox will throw a warning. See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL1mC.jpg)

**3 ways to solve this**

1. Click on "I understand the risk", and Add Exception, and then click on "add a permanent exception" (But I do not completely recommend that)
2. You can use a trick. All you have to do is to go to [Ask question page of the French StackExchange](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and down there you will see the "login with facebook and others"... and login from there.
3. Stack Exchange can change their CDN and any other https address using the https protocol that Firefox classify as untrusted and  use one which is accepted in all major browser's last version.

Comment: So it looks like a Firefox bug, I see this in Chrome: http://i.stack.imgur.com/j4SAJ.png

Comment: @ManOfGod I did that (the trich number 2). I am logged in now but still the website can not display well at all. I had to access the website by going to http://french.stackexchange.com/ instead of https://french.stackexchange.com/. I think you are right and even the https address of the french stackexchange is not trusted by firefox. Hope StackExchange will do something about it

Comment: @ShadowWizard There is no problem with Chrome. It works perfectly in Chrome but the problem is between Firefox and some https

Comment: @John I know there is no problem in Chrome, that's what I said - the problem is with Firefox which can't identify trusted connection for some reason. :/